# Como fazer reload de página com angular de acordo com o queryparms

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Eu tenho um input simples que serve como componente de pesquisa, com a função de submit

```
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (!this.searchForm.valid) {
      this.submitted = false;

    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['searchResult/'], {queryParams: {searchText: this.searchForm.get('searchText').value}});
    }
  }
```

Após feito isso, ele vai para a página de resultados, que apresenta os resultados corretos. Porém nessa página eu tenho o mesmo componente, que ao fazer a pesquisa novamente, altera o valor da minha URL. Contudo, a pesquisa não é realizada novamente.

Acredito que o ngOnInit já foi iniciado, e eu precisaria de outra forma para fazer o "reload do ngOnInit" como fazer isso? Dei uma pesquisa no NgOnChange mas acredito que não seja o que estou precisando no momento.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.searchTextResult = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('searchText');
    this.getHerosResultByName();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu resolvi colocando um subscribe no meu constructor

```
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe((params) => {
      this.searchTextResult = params.get('searchText');
      this.getHerosResultByName();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

O `ngOnChanges` é acionado quando um valor de `@Input()` muda, mudanças ocorridas dentro do componente não disparam este evento. Você pode testar outra alternativa, ao invés de acionar a rota. Use um `BehaviorSubject` para acionar o filtro, no ngOnInit, você apenas subscreve ao `observable` do mesmo:

```
private searchText = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
searchText$ = this.searchText.asObservable();

ngOnInit() {
  this.searchText$
    .pipe(
      shareReplay(),
    )
    .subscribe((text) => {
      if ( text !== '' ) {
        this.searchTextResult = text
        this..getHerosResultByName();
      }
    })
}

onSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;
  if (this.searchForm.valid) {
    this.searchText.next(this.searchForm.get('searchText').value)
  }
}
```

Da forma acima, toda vez que o valor do `observable` mudar o filtro será aplicado. Sem reload.

Comment: Não funcionou meu caso. Acho que porque ngOnInit é só disparado uma vez.  Mas eu não tinha ciência o behavior subject, vou dar uma estudada